# Mounting Azure file share resulted in mount error(13):Permission denied

Tags: azure, centos7, azure-virtual-machine

This question is discussed many times in this forum and many solution were given which works on case to case basis.I faced this issue and found after 1 day that issue happened because while creation of storage account I made enabled "Secure Transfer required" option due to which whenever I was trying to mount this file share it was giving me error.

Now my problem is:

- I could not find any documentation in Microsoft knowledge base asking to not do this.
- Why is this an issue in first place. Isn't enabling this option make my file share more secure.
- Can I mount my file share in any way with this option enabled?

I am using cento 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could not find any documentation in Microsoft knowledge base asking
>   to not do this.

The "Secure transfer required" option enhances the security of your storage account by only allowing requests to the account from secure connections. For example, when you're calling REST APIs to access your storage account, you must connect by using **HTTPS**. "Secure transfer required" rejects requests that use HTTP.

> Why i this an issue in first place. Isnt enabling this option make my
>   file share more secure.

Here a similar [case](https://serverfault.com/questions/862860/mount-error-13-with-ubuntu-16-04-and-azure-same-region) about you, please refer to it.

> Can I mount my file share in any way with this option enabled?

Centos 7.4 support the encryption functionality of SMB 3.0, we should **turn off** secure transfer required, and mount it direct.

> When you use the Azure Files service, any connection without
>   encryption fails when "Secure transfer required" is enabled. This
>   includes scenarios that use SMB 2.1, SMB 3.0 without encryption, and
>   some versions of the Linux SMB client.

More information about secure transfer required, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer).